# problem while starting android virtual device

Tags: android-emulator

whenever I start any virtual device, it gives this error

invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information

Platform in android 2.3.3, windows xp ....

Comment: Have you created a AVD with the SDK yet?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is with eclipse IDE, it would not recognise your sdk until you sets path which don't have any spaces, e.g., if your Android home is something like, c:\program files\android, your AVD will not launch, it will through error which you have in your cause, to overcome this move whole Android home folder to single directory path like, c:\android\ , it worked for me.